# SightlyCompilerException: BinaryOperator.strictEq

Tags: aem, sling, sightly

Need your help in resolving below exceptions: getting below exception post migration from AEM 6.1 to AEM 6.3.

This exception occurs when trying to render/load an HTML page.

All bundles are in active state.

> 27.09.2017 10:15:31.272 *ERROR* [10.5.2.154 [1506500131064] GET /content/suninternational/properties/table-bay.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.compiler.SightlyCompilerException: Operands are not of the same type: the equality operator can only be applied to String, Number and Boolean types.
>   at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.compiler.expression.nodes.BinaryOperator.strictEq(Bina ryOperator.java:238)
>   at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.apps.suninternational.components.content.flyoutCompone nt.flyoutComponent_html.render(flyoutComponent_html.java:81)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you're doing an equality comparison between incompatible types (String vs. Number, Object vs. Number/String).

Judging by the provided stacktrace the issue is happening somewhere in `apps/suninternational/components/content/flyoutComponent/flyoutComponent.html`